# Not receiving the password from credential Request

Tags: java, android

I'm currently trying out a code to get credentials from emails/gmail account and I found a skeleton code online. But after running it on my old android I found that although I could get the id, I could not get the password. Is there a reason? why?

```
private void requestCredentials() {
        // Request all of the user's saved username/password credentials.  We are not using
        // setAccountTypes so we will not load any credentials from other Identity Providers.
        CredentialRequest request = new CredentialRequest.Builder()
                .setPasswordLoginSupported(true)
                .setAccountTypes(IdentityProviders.GOOGLE)
                .build();

        mCredentialsClient.request(request).addOnCompleteListener(
                new OnCompleteListener<CredentialRequestResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<CredentialRequestResponse> task) {
                        hideProgress();

                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            // Successfully read the credential without any user interaction, this
                            // means there was only a single credential and the user has auto
                            // sign-in enabled.
                            processRetrievedCredential(task.getResult().getCredential(), false);
                            return;
                        }
    }
```

```
private void processRetrievedCredential(Credential credential, boolean isHint) {

        mEmailField.setText(credential.getId());
        mPasswordField.setText(credential.getPassword());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As official document states:

> If the ID of a retrieved credential matches the ID of an account
> signed-in of the device, the credential will contain an ID token that
> you can use to authenticate without a password.

You can read more about it here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/retrieve-credentials

and here:

https://developers.google.com/identity/smartlock-passwords/android/idtoken-auth

Comment: does that mean it will not be possible to get the password for any account? as the IDtoken will be used in replaced of it

Comment: @palawite you still can get the password of account types that are not equals to IdentityProviders.GOOGLE. for accounts like gmail, only id is returned.